# jQuery: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am a new jQuery user and i have a problem. Sometimes I get this error:

```
jquery.min.js:2 POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/run/wellness net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
k.<computed> @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ wellness:97
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery.min.js:2
```

JavaScript:

```js
  
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#scrape').on('click', () => {
      
        var specialty = []; 
        $("input:checkbox[name=specialty]:checked").each(function() { 
          specialty.push($(this).val()); 
        });
        
        $.post('/run/wellness', {'specialty': specialty}, (res) => {
          $.each(res.data, function(index, card) { 
            var content = '<div class="card mb-3 border border-black" style="max-width: 1195px; background-color: white; margin:0 auto">'
            content += '<div class="row no-gutters">'
            content += '<div class="col-md-8">'
            content += '<div class="card-body">'
            content += '<h5 class="card-title"><strong>' + 
                       card.First_and_Last_Name + ' | ' +
                       Phone + '</strong></h5>'
            content += '<small>' + Address + '</small>'
            content += '<p class="card-text" style="width: 1160px;">' + card.About + '</p>'
            content += '</div></div></div></div>'
            $('#output').append(content)
          }); 
        });
      });
    </script>
```

What am I doing wrong here. Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a server error. You should check on your server errors logs.

Comment: I use Flask, there were no errors in the log. Data was sent from the site, despite the error.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm getting the same problem. Flask shows that the request was handled and that the response was sent, but Chrome DevTools shows ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Answer (score 0):

Adding to all AJAX requests **async: false** helps me. Like this:

```js
$.ajax({
  async: false,
  type: 'post',
  success: function() {
    ...
  }
});
```